# What's the problem with this angular ts code for implementing floating label input onfocus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to float the labels onfocusing input in angular.

I did wrote code to perform the action of a class to be applied on focusing the input, & then focus out to check empty value or values present, to remove the applied class.

***forms.component.html***

```
<div class="forms-field-box">
    <div class="forms-field-inp-box">
        <input id="forms_field_inp_fn" class="forms-field-inp" type="text" (focus)=inpAnim();>
        <label for="forms_field_inp_fn" id="forms_input" class="forms-field-inp-lbl">
            FirstName
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="forms-field-box">
    <div class="forms-field-inp-box">
        <input id="forms_field_inp_ln" class="forms-field-inp" type="text" (focus)=inpAnim();>
        <label for="forms_field_inp_ln" id="forms_input" class="forms-field-inp-lbl">
            LastName
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="forms-field-box">
    <div class="forms-field-inp-box">
        <input id="forms_field_inp_p" class="forms-field-inp" type="text" (focus)=inpAnim();>
        <label for="forms_field_inp_p" id="forms_input" class="forms-field-inp-lbl">
            Password
        </label>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="forms-login-btn">
    Login
</div>
```

***forms.component.scss***

```
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.forms-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    min-height: 120px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.forms-field-box {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.forms-field-inp-box {
    width: 97%;
    position: relative;
}

.forms-field-inp {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    outline: none;
    padding: 6px;
}

.forms-field-inp:hover {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.forms-field-inp:focus {
    border: 1px solid #0089ff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.forms-field-inp-lbl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    user-select:none;
    color: #cccccc;
}

.forms-field-inp-lbl-anim ~ .forms-field-inp-lbl {
    top: -9px;
}

.forms-login-btn {
    width: 20%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
}
```

***forms.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forms',
  templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms.component.scss']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    
    
   
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
      
  inpAnim(){

  let forms_input_ele:any = document.querySelector(".forms-field-inp-box input");

    forms_input_ele.addEventListener("focusin", () => { 
      console.log("focussed in");
      forms_input_ele.classList.add("forms-field-inp-lbl-anim");

    } );

    forms_input_ele.addEventListener("focusout", () => { 
      let forms_inp_val = forms_input_ele.value;
      if(forms_inp_val == ""){
        forms_input_ele.classList.remove("forms-field-inp-lbl-anim");
        console.log("focussed out");
        console.log(forms_inp_val);
      }
     });
    }


}
```

Please Help me to solve this.

[input focused & label floated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQC1K.png)

[input has value & label stays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSJsm.png)

Problem: But, the first input only works, other inputs not working if focused & nothing happens.,
[Next input is focused, but label not floating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Awl.png)

*This can be easily applied by css, but need to make this small code to work correctly*

Comment: What exactly are those event listeners and why do you need them?

Comment: I just added eventlisteners to listen from input, if its focused in & out

Comment: I think the correct event names are focus and blur. And you are already using (focus) in your template (and you can also use (blur)). Also, it’s not a great idea to use direct DOM manipulation to add/remove classes. You have [ngClass] for that..

Comment: I will try that, thank u for ur response :)